# Exported function doesn't expand awk variable

Tags: bash, awk

I have a bash function, which takes two parameters and calls an awk command.

Calling the function inside another awk command from main script.

The issue is the "if" condition in the awk inside the function doesn't work.

$2==obj is not working in below code. If "literal" value is given, it works fine.

```
function func1() {
APPNAME=$1
OBJ_TYPE=$2
    while read -r next_obj
    do
        <Command> ${APPNAME} | grep "$OBJ_TYPE" | awk -v APPNAME="$APPNAME" -v obj="${next_obj}" '$2==obj {print APPNAME}'
    done < <input File>

}
export -f func1

<Command> | grep -iv ok | awk -v OBJ_TYPE="$OBJ_TYPE" '{ if ($2 == "started") { system("func1 " $1" "OBJ_TYPE) } }'
```

Comment: Using `system()` in awk is a *very* bad idea -- it's prone to major security bugs (since unlike running code natively in shell, data that should be treated literally is run through the full parser), doesn't support exported functions on systems where `/bin/sh` is not bash, and is also very slow. Perhaps you might use native bash for your file I/O?

Comment: That said, the bigger problem with this question is that it isn't, as currently given, a [mcve] -- someone else can't copy-and-paste without changes to see the problem themselves, and so we can't test answers for correctness. Stubs like `<Command>` should be filled in with some *specific* command, even if it's not the real one you're working with, so long as it generates output that makes the problem observable.

Comment: the question is "How to use awk inside a function, regarding dollar concurrency"... `echo 1 | awk '$1 == $1 {print $1;}'`